# Authenticating with PHP $_SESSION

Tags: php, html, session

I have a code to log in to a database system and do some simple tasks like view user details, edit user details kind of tasks.  After logging in, a user should have the ability to log out. My question arise here. I need to redirect to a page which display some text(logoff.php page) and then redirect to the index page. But once I click the logout link it directly goes to the index page which is the login page.

a user is redirected to the log off page from a page and my logoff.php code is this

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["uname"])) {
    unset($_SESSION["uname"]);
}
header("Location:../index.php");
exit;
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Logged Off</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br><br>
        <div align="">
            <h2>You are now logged off</h2>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="../index.php">home</a></div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

It should show the text if a user is redirected to here. But I am sure that it comes to this page since it shows the text inside html tags when I remove the php part of the code. I think the problem is with `$_SESSION`code segment. Doesn't it authenticate the user? Is that the reason why I am redirected to the index page with out listing the content of the logoff page?

My index page which is used for logging is this.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $mess="";

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])&&$_POST["submit"]=="Sign in") {
        //conncet to the database
        require_once("./dbcon/user.php");
        include("./dbcon/dbcon.php"); //database connection function

        $user=$_POST["uname"];
        $password=md5($_POST["password"]);
        //retriving data from db
        $query = "SELECT user_name FROM user_info WHERE user_name = '$user' AND password ='$password'";
        $result=mysql_query($query);

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $name=$row["0"];
        }

        if(mysql_affected_rows()==0) {
            $mess = "<font color=purple size=2><b>Wrong username or password.<br>Please try again.</b></font>";

        } else {
            $_SESSION["uname"]=$name;
            header("Location:./user/user1.php");
            exit;
        }
    }
?>

<html>
    <!-- html form -->
</html>
```

In this case do I need to include index.php page into the logoff.php page because SESSION variable is created in the index.php page? Is that the reason or any other?
Thanks!

Comment: hope there is a exit and also a redirection? is that so?

Comment: As soon as your script hits `header("Location:../index.php");`, the browser will just go to the directed page.  Once your script hits `exit;`, it's going to exit.  If you want to display your "logout" page and then redirect, consider using a meta refresh or some javascript to do the redirect.

Comment: @LifeHacker once I click logout link on a page which is not here, it should come to the logoff page given here.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in that line, and is a feature, not a bug :

```
header("Location:../index.php");
```

This does the redirection server side so that your user never gets to see the page body as he only receives this header, telling the browser to go the that URL.

instead of doing this, you should either use a javascript redirect function with `setTimeout()` , or use the meta-refresh which is really indicated in this case I guess :

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL=yourindexpage.php" />
```

Note the `10` in the line here above, it indicates the delay in seconds before the redirection occurs.

Comment: Once the script sees the redirect it takes place and the rest of that script is not executed.

Comment: @BrettSantore Incorrect, the browser isn't obligated to honor a header redirect.  You have to add an `exit();` in there to guarantee code doesn't get executed past a certain point.

Comment: Indeed. This `header()` function only sends back info to the browser and is like any other instruction in a PHP perspective, it doesn't stop script execution at all, at least for what I know. The best proof of that is that if you try to do an `echo` after that, you'll get an error, meaning that the line was indeed hit.

Comment: Isn't there anything wrong with user authentication with SESSION?

Comment: @buddhiweerasinghe > well, if you want to keep the data alive, I see no better solution than Session...

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION["uname"])) {
        unset($_SESSION["uname"]);
    }
    ?>

    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Logged Off</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <br><br>
            <div align="">
                <h2>You are now logged off</h2>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="../index.php">home</a></div>
        </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: do not I have any error there with user authentication?